# Использование extern "C" в методе класса

Tags: классы, c++

В хидере стороннего разработчика dll описан прототип функции:

> extern  "C" void __stdcall AnyFunction()

1. Мне необходимо сделать его статическим, пытаюсь вписать его в класс получаю ошибку - error C2059: syntax error : 'string', без extern  "C" принимает, как быть?
2. Как прописать реализацию метода вне объявления класса, тоже не получается!

Код:

```
 class clssMy{
 public:
       extern  "C" static void __stdcall AnyFunction();
 };
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Модификатор `extern "C"` нельзя использовать для методов класса.

Это так потому, что `extern "C"` требует линковки, совместимой с C (то есть, без name mangling), а методам классов нужны "декорированные" имена.

А для чего вам extern "C" в классе? Вам это не должно быть нужно.

Comment: AnyFunction() является функцией обратного вызова со стороны DLL, библиотека написана на C, вот хочу сделать её статической и поместить в класс. Это же возможно?

Comment: Нет :( Именно из-за проблем с именами. Но вы можете сделать отдельную функцию, вне класса, и объявить её с extern "C". И в ней уже вызывать (другую) статическую функцию класса.

Comment: Досадно...

Comment: @rejie: а почему отдельная функция вам не подходит?

Comment: Подходит, просто хотелось инкапсулировать всё в класс!